# How do I assign and control user permissions for editing ranges using VBA in an Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I've been struggling with this issue for a few weeks now; I can't find a solution and I am genuinely starting to think this task can't be done with VBA code.

### My setup:

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit with MS Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO 32-bit Version 2108, with the Rights Management Service Client 2.1 from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38396
and I do not have admin privileges on my machine.

### Explanation of the problem:

I am trying to write VBA code to automate an Excel spreadsheet overtime tracker for my division.  This task was previously done by hand in Excel and took many hours to complete, as there are more than 130 individuals spread across 6 different groups, each group in its own workbook.  (Additionally, these overtime workbooks/worksheets have established formats and layouts that have been used for several years, and cannot be overhauled to an entirely new scheme:  I need to keep the structure and appearance as they are now.)

I have code in my spreadsheet that loops through the workers' names and specifies the cells they may edit:

```
Sub EditRngByWorker()
    Dim allowedEditRng as AllowEditRange
    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="AWorker", Range:=Range _
         ("B3,D3:D42,D44:D46"), Password:="WorkerPassword"
End Sub
```

But I also need to associate their UserID (or organizational email address) with the range that is assigned to them.  To do this, I need to assign permissions, and I want to do the assigning with VBA code.

### My Questions:

How do I select the "Permissions" button from the "Allow Users to Edit Ranges" dialog and Add permissions for AWorker using VBA code?

Here are the dialog boxes as I have to deal with them right now:
[image: figure]

After that, how do I fill in the information in the "Select Users, Computers, Service Accounts, or Groups" dialog box using VBA code?  I know everyone in my division's UserIDs, email addresses, and full names.

This is an example "Select Users, Computers, Service Accounts, or Groups" dialog that I want to fill out using VBA code, instead of by hand:
[image: figure]

When I am finished with the VBA code for this workbook, it will be saved to a shared network drive and will need to be accessible to everyone in the division without a password to open it.

Here is the VBA code I have right now for permissions...

```
Sub SetPermissions()
    Dim myPermission as Office.Permission
    Dim userPermission as Office.UserPermission
    Set myPermission = ThisWorkBook.Permission
    myPermission.Add UserID:="AWorker@domain.net", _
                     Permission:=msoPermissionChange + msoPermissionRead + msoPermissionPrint
End Sub
```

...but when I run it I get the error

> Run-time error '5':  Invalid procedure call or argument

Am I missing something about how to work with the RMS Client?
Am I missing a very specialized piece of code, a file, or a .dll?
Do I need Admin privileges to get permissions to work in VBA code?
Or am I correct and Permissions are no longer supported by Microsoft?

Sorry so long, and thank you in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: I would go with 1 sheet per person which is passworded so only they can see or edit. Then a master sheet that calls the info for each person.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, I need the workers in each job group to be on the same sheet so they can exchange their overtime hours.  Many of the users are not very computer literate and will not be able to navigate 130 workbook tabs.  I need to keep each group on its own worksheet.  Thanks.

Comment: Then have 1 workbook per job group, or 26 (26 letters in the alphabet - sure your workers could follow...) or A-G, H-P & Q_z, whatever works. Or They could use goto and go to the sheet names they need. Think out of the box.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, I already do have one workbook for each job group and I need to assign user permissions for each worker in their group based on their User ID (or email address) in the organization.  I need to do this using VBA to save time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient post that I had bookmarked sometime for some reason.
Thoughts to research if anyone hit this page again.

- Lock/protect the entire sheet with an admin password.
- Use VBA to determine who is logged in, I'm sure that code is out there.
- Unlock user's specific range for updating.
- Lock the sheet with workbook on-close action.

This presumes each user range is a block of cells. You can avoid creating dedicated ranges per user, just unlock the block relative the user's name/id cell.

Second idea:

- Create a user input area on top of the big worksheet.
- Have an 'get my data' button to write user's data block up in the input area.
- Change to a 'save my data' button to write it back into the worksheet body.
  If users need to scroll around other folks' time, then lock the input area rows visible on top with those underneath scrollable.
- This method allows you to keep the entire worksheet body locked/protected below input area.

Cheers